# MVC Entity Framework Error on Mapping Entity with [NotMapped] properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper, model-binding

I have define a `Entity` call `Users`...that is mapped to `Users` table with EF.

```html
 public partial class Users
    {
        public long User_id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "LastName cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Country_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> State_id { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpDateTime { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^.{5,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 characters required")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be longer than 9 characters.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int Rol_id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
        public string CodArea { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual Ages Ages { get; set; }
        public virtual Countries Countries { get; set; }
        [NotMapped] // Does not effect with your database
        [RegularExpression(@"^.{5,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 characters required")]
        [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password cannot be longer than 9 characters.")]
        [Compare("Password")]
        public virtual string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

I use this entity to inherit from my `Create` View...

When I Update, I do not need a lot of this properties. I defined a a new Entity called `UserEditView` with this definition. I do not have Password and ConfirmPassword.

```html
public partial class UserEditView 
    {
        public long User_id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "LastName cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Country_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> State_id { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpDateTime { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^.{5,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 characters required")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be longer than 9 characters.")]
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
        public string CodArea { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

I defined a `Mapper` in my Global asax and Ignore those properties I dot not need.

```html
 cfg.CreateMap<Users, UserEditView>();
                                     cfg.CreateMap<UserEditView, Users>()
                                          .ForMember(x => x.CreationDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
                                                                        .ForMember(x => x.Password, opt => opt.Ignore())
                                                                        .ForMember(x => x.ConfirmPassword, opt => opt.Ignore())
                                                                        .ForMember(x => x.Rol_id, opt => opt.Ignore());
                                    }
```

When I Update, I mapp `UserEditView` to `Users` so I can call `_db.SaveChanges()` like this.

```html
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(UserEditView model, System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase image = null)
{
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View(model);
                }
                model.user.UpDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                model.user.IP = Request.UserHostAddress;
                model.user.Url = UserValidation.EncriptacionURL(model.user.Email);


                var user = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.User_id == model.user.User_id);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return View(model);
                }
                Mapper.Map<UserEditView, Users>(model.user, user);
               _db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
}
```

in user I have the data I have in `Users` table. So `ConfirmPassword` is null because it is set as  `[NotMapped]`.
On `_db.SaveChanges()` I have an error because `ConfirmPassword` is null, so, when it is compared with `Users` Entity, it is compared whith `Password` property and failed.

How can I work when using `[NotMapped]` properties there is null?

Thanks

Comment: when  decorate `[NotMapped]` on your property, it not create in your database

Comment: I know, it there is the problem... When I do SaveChanges, ConfirmPassword is null, But in Users Entity says that has to match with Password property... and get me an error because of that... My question is, that If it is null, how can I omit Entity Validation when I do SaveChanges?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had in a Property `ConfirmPassword` I have add to my `Users` Entity with the Notation `[NotMapped]`. That case me a problem, when I do AutoMapper to Update Modified fields. Entity Validation ocurrs and ConfirmPassowrd is null, so, when validations ocurrs, I had an error on `SaveChanges();`.

I solved it adding

> context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;